# Does xpath containing preceding-sibling or following-sibling are supposed to be of same tag?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

suppose my HTML structure is :

```
 <div class='parent'>

      <a class="child"> PI </a> 

      <div class="child>CP </div>  

      <a class="child>A </a>

      <a class="child>B </a>

  </div>
```

Parent div has 4 child and i need to click on the child div.Is this following
  xpath valid? Or the preceding siblings means they have to be of same 'a' tag.

```
//a[contains(text(),'A')]/preceding-sibling::div[contains(text(),'CP')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath is valid. The `preceding-sibling` axis selector:

> Indicates all the nodes that have the same parent as the context node and appear before the context node in the source document.
>   If the context node is an attribute node or namespace node, the `preceding-sibling` axis is empty

Same for `following-sibling`, except of course, it:

> Indicates all the nodes that have the same parent as the context node and appear after the context node in the source document.

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes